# rake is aborted in rails as it says active support is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

hi im trying to run rails server on a machine 
it says that no such file to load error

so i tried to run rake and found that rake aborted no such file to load -- active support
below is the error

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- active_support

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

please help

This is what is says when i try to start a new rails project

```
[username]$ rails new blog
LoadError: no such file to load -- active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using rvm? Have you definitely installed rails?

`gem install rails`

`bundle install`

`rails new blog`

Comment: yes, all those are there "[username ~]$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.6" it shows the version here but not able to create a rails app

Comment: try gem install activesupport